# Photo to email directly from Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-xp, email, images

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What would be the easiest way of quickly mailing a file through GMail ?](https://superuser.com/questions/86752/what-would-be-the-easiest-way-of-quickly-mailing-a-file-through-gmail)

My uncle ( he is a press photographer) sends about 30-40 photos in email on a daily basis. He uses Gmail and attaches every image as an [attachment in mail](http://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=114590&cbid=-1gcn4ryfkd65o&src=cb&lev=answer) and then sends the email to a group (which has 150 email addresses).

Is there any free software to send photo to multiple emails directly, somewhat like select all photos in a folder then send ?

Comment: Dupe of http://superuser.com/questions/86752/what-would-be-the-easiest-way-of-quickly-mailing-a-file-through-gmail ?

Answer (score 0):

Use a mail client like [Thunderbird 3](http://www.mozillamessaging.com/en-US/thunderbird/). Configure Thunderbird [to use GMail](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Using_Gmail_with_Thunderbird_and_Mozilla_Suite). Then go to the folder, select all and click on send to -> Email client. The pics will be sent to Thunderbird 3, provided it's the default client and you can send the mails.

[image: send to mail]

Answer (score 0):

Doing for Gmail what the MailTo link does for Outlook, the wonderfully simple **[gAttach](http://download.cnet.com/gAttach/3000-2367_4-10861891.html)** is a small utility that reassigns Gmail as the default mail account from Windows documents. With gAttach installed, selecting Send from Windows Explorer, Firefox, and Microsoft Office automatically attaches the files to a Gmail composition.

[image]

*gAttach is freeware.*

Comment: with this can we send photos directly without going or opening gmail in browser?

Comment: well it will open a browser window with Gmail Compose Mail and the files you want to send already attached. you will have to enter the recipient and hit the send button yourself :)